# Adding comments and likes to the object laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel

I'm writing applications from tutorial for booking tourist objects in laravel 8. I have a problem redirecting to the website after adding a comment and liking the object. When I click "like" or "add comment" it shows me an error below. Any ideas what im doing wrong?

Error:

```
Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.52 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1m PHP/7.4.27 Server at localhost Port 80
```

My files for likes

Object.blade.php:

```
@auth

      @if( $touristObject->isLiked() )
     <a href="{{ route('unlike',['likeable_id'=>$touristObject->id,'type'=>'App\TouristObject']) }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs top-buffer">Odlub ten obiekt</a>
      @else
         <a href="{{ route('like',['likeable_id'=>$touristObject->id,'type'=>'App\TouristObject']) }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs top-buffer">Polub ten obiekt</a>
      @endif

  @else

  <p><a href="{{ route('login') }}">Zaloguj się aby polubić obiekt</a></p>

  @endauth
```

FrontendController:

```
public function like($likeable_id, $type, Request $request)
    {
      $this->fR->like($likeable_id, $type, $request);

      return redirect()->back();
    }

    public function unlike($likeable_id, $type, Request $request)
    {
      $this->fR->unlike($likeable_id, $type, $request);

      return redirect()->back();
    }
```

FrontendRepository:

```
public function like($likeable_id, $type, $request)
  {
    $likeable = $type::find($likeable_id);

    return $likeable->users()->attach($request->user()->id);
  }

  public function unlike($likeable_id, $type, $request)
  {
    $likeable = $type::find($likeable_id);

    return $likeable->users()->detach($request->user()->id);
  }
```

Model TouristObject:

```
  public function isLiked()
        {
            return $this->users()->where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)->exists();
        }
```

---

My files for comments

object.blade.php:

```
  @auth

    <a class="btn btn-primary" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
        Dodaj komentarz
    </a>

    @else
    <p><a href="{{ route('login') }}">Zaloguj się aby dodać komentarz</a></p>
    @endauth


    <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
        <div class="well">


            <form method="POST" action="{{ route('addComment',['commentable_id'=>$touristObject->id, 'App\TouristObject']) }}" class="form-horizontal">
                <fieldset>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="textArea" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Skomentuj</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-10">
                            <textarea required name="content" class="form-control" rows="3" id="textArea"></textarea>
                            <span class="help-block">Dodaj komentarz do tego obiektu</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

FrontendRepository:

```
public function addComment($commentable_id, $type, $request)
  {
    $commentable = $type::find($commentable_id);

    $comment = new Comment;
    $comment->content = $request->input('content');
    $comment->rating = $type == 'App\TouristObject' ? $request->input('content') : 0;
    $comment->user_id = $request->user()->id;

    return $commentable->comments()->save($comment);
  }
```

FrontendGateway:

```
    public function addComment($commentable_id, $type, $request)
      {
        $this->validate($request, [
          'content' => "required|string"
    
        ]);
    
        return $this->fR->addComment($commentable_id, $type, $request);
    
    
      }
```

Routes:

```
Route::get('/like/{likeable_id}/{type}','FrontendController@like')->name('like');
Route::get('/unlike/{likeable_id}/{type}','FrontendController@unlike')->name('unlike');

Route::post('/addComment/{commentable_id}/{type}','FrontendController@addComment')->name('addComment');
```

Comment: what is the URL of the page where you are clicking "like" or "add"?

Comment: pls show me your URL of the page.

Comment: URL http://localhost/testowa7/public/addComment/4/App%5CTouristObject

Comment: @lagbox please help, when i change Path in object.blade.php From 'App/TouristObject' for "App\TouristObject" the URL is without % but there is error 404 page not found